# wss 3.0 to Sharepoint 2010 Foundation Upgrade Problem

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, upgrade

Just did a Database attach Upgrade from wss 3.0 to sharepoint 2010 Foundation. I detached the content database from wss 3.0 Webapplication with internal database running in Windows Server 2008 R2. I went to another virtual box with installed sharepoint 2010 foundation version with SQL Server 2008 Internal Database. I detached the content db of site collection and used stsadm -o addcontentdb to attach the content db of wss 3.0. It sucessfully completed with some errors saying found missing feature ID of custom Solutions.

Custom webparts seems to act fine but when i click into the lists, calendars, DVWP and try to add a new item it gives me error "FILE NOT FOUND". 
!([image: ERROR]

I took a look at LOG file with USL viewer it say:"
Site=/

Leaving Monitored Scope (PostResolveRequestCacheHandler). Execution Time=1962.63268096923

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:_wpresources\RadEditorSharePoint\6.1.6.0__1f131a624888eeed\Resources\ListToolsFile.xml'.
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
 at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
 at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
 at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
 at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
 at Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor.get_ToolsFileContent()
 at Telerik.Web.UI.ToolsFileLoader.LoadColors(EditorColorCollection colors)
 at Telerik.Web.UI.RadEditor.LoadToolsFile(Boolean loadOnlyEmptyCollections)
 at Telerik.SharePoint.RadTextField.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://hhq2010:48438/Lists/Roll%20Call/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fdhq2010%3A48438%2Fdefault%2Easpx)). Execution Time=700.180330181629

I Dont know what is going on. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back on the WSS 3 site, deactivate and remove the telerik feature, then take the database and roll it to SP2010. The telerik feature handles changing the rich text editors to the telerik rad editor. Removing it should resolve your issue.

Comment: Excellent! Please check off as answered ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you reinstall Telerik properly on your new environment?

Comment: Nope I did not, Can i take it off completely. Would that take the references off the lists.

Comment: It won't take the reference off the lists no. You'll need to do each of them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with James on this, it seems your list is trying to use the Telerik RADEditor. Telerik is not really needed anymore in SP2010 seeing as that provides much richer editing capabilities.

- option 1: opening the pages in SharePoint Designer and remove and and all references to the Telerik assemblies and controls using the code view
- As a workaround, you could try and copy the `wpresources` from the `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions` folder on the old machine to the the same location on the new machine, so the page'll at least load, because it should now be able to load the xml file it is looking for, which is stored in the radeditor's deployment folder, in `wpresources`. (well, maybe, might still be an assembly issue seeing as the old version will be targetting the 12.0 version of the SP assemblies.) 
  2 options:

Comment: Thank You Colin I took Telirak editor solution off. It started working Thank You

Comment: Colin i have wss 3.0 solutions deployed in 30 diffrent client. Some client are running it on windows server 2003 some in server 2008. MOst of them have internal database.What would be the best approach to take to start testing the upgrade. Do you think the approach i am taking in efficient and right?